# Mapping SD card on networked raspberry pi from linux

Tags: networking, sd-card

I'd like to map my raspberry pi's sd card from my linux laptop, so I can directly edit text files without using vim. How would I do this?

Comment: I've now tried using Samba, this doesn't work as I'm unable to overwrite files, also Sublime Text doesn't natively support opening files located on a samba share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install *sshfs* and possibly *fuse* on your laptop
2. On your laptop create a directory on which you will mount your RPi `$ mkdir /mnt/rpi`
3. On your laptop add the following line to your `/etc/fstab` file (sudo) changing the xxx to the actual RPI ip address

   `sshfs#pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/rpi fuse user,noauto,uid=0,gid=0,follow_symlinks,defaults 0 0`
4. Finally mount: `$ mount /mnt/rpi`

Comment: An excellent example of a stackexchange answer. I also had to install sshfs, this wasn't part of the fuse package I had as default

Any idea how I would add a password into /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Best way is to work with ssh keys. To generate them on your laptop: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Leave passphrase blank. This will generate a private key: `id_rsa` that you will keep on the laptop, and a `id_rsa.pub` public key that you will append to the PRi's `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and you are set. You can check by ssh-ing your RPi from command line. If successful you shouldn't be asked for a password. For more detailed instructions, Google OpenSSH keys.

Comment: @joseph indeed, sshfs should also be installed. Post corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Samba is one option - probably you just have permissions wrong
NFS is another option

If Sublime Text can't work with networked filesystems I guess you need to choose a different editor.

You can also run an editor (doesn't have to be vim) on the raspberrypi

For text based editor you just ssh in and fire it up

For graphical editor, make sure you have "ForwardX11 yes" in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and fire it up